# JQuery - How to move a li to another position in the ul? (exchange 2 li's)

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html-lists

What is a cool way to apply this? I need a script that exchange two < li>'s position in an < ul>.
It think that should be possible to achieve. Thanks for your response.

HTML

```
<div id="awesome">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Pseudo Javascript (JQuery)

```
$("#awesome ul li:eq(1)").exchangePostionWith("#awesome ul li:eq(3)");
```

HTML Result

```
<div id="awesome">
<ul>
<li>Item 1</li>
<li>Item 4</li>
<li>Item 3</li>
<li>Item 2</li>
<li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use jQuery's `.after()` for moving elements around. I cloned one of them so the original can remain as a placeholder. It's like if you wanted to switch variables `a` and `b`, you'd need a third temporary variable.

```
$.fn.exchangePositionWith = function(selector) {
    var other = $(selector);
    this.after(other.clone());
    other.after(this).remove();
};
```

Now your pseudocode `$("#awesome ul li:eq(1)").exchangePositionWith("#awesome ul li:eq(3)");` isn't so pseudo :-)

Answer (score 3):

```
 $("ul li a").click(function () {
    $(this).parent().insertBefore('ul li:eq(0)');
  });


<ul>
    <li><a>a</a></li>
    <li><a>b</a></li>
    <li><a>c</a></li>
    <li><a>d</a></li>
    <li><a>e</a></li>
    <li><a>f</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It is removed my values on click