# Rearrange order of <ul> to keep active element in center

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to construct a menu which keeps the active li in the same position when you click on it and adds a class to the adjacent li (so they can be styled)
The idea is, allows me to create a "3D wheel" effect - i.e. the clicked element sits in the centre of the ul vertically.

```
 <div id="container">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li class="adj">2</li>
        <li class="active">3</li>
        <li class="adj">4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Styling it is fairly straightforward but re-ordering without bolting on a plugin is proving more difficult.

http://jsfiddle.net/vDb3L/2/

The closest I have come is using the technique Box9 demonstrates [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612955/jquery-how-to-move-a-li-to-another-position-in-the-ul-exchange-2-lis) by swapping the active element with the third element. 
However this leaves the adjacent elements static which doesn't look great,

```
$.fn.exchangePositionWith = function(selector) {
var other = $(selector);
this.after(other.clone());
other.after(this).remove();
};

$(this).addClass('active').exchangePositionWith('#frontpage_slider_menu li:eq(2)');
```

Any idea to reorder the ul, so that the active element is always in the middle with the correct adjacent li?
[Stackoverflow - Referred.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612955/jquery-how-to-move-a-li-to-another-position-in-the-ul-exchange-2-lis)

Comment: Interesting problem; but I might still be unclear what you're looking for with "reordering the ul" - will some of the elements be swapping places? Since I don't think transitions tend to work with element removal/moving, part of me is thinking of a more complex solution where you abandon standard layout entirely, and use additive transform2d's to put blocks in the correct place.

Comment: @Katana314 my reasoning was that this type of approach allows it all to be placed relative to each other, whereas a transform/positioning approach forces it to be absolute. Less code/less intensive? (maybe?)

Comment: I understand your sentiments - my thinking was just that all positioning is absolute in the very end. You'd be doing some of the math in positioning yourself, but as long as this option wheel only contains known element types, you could pretty easily calculate positions based on "intended" index.