# How to shift all <li> inside a <ul> except a particular <li> one position left and right on left button click and right button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my html , now  I want to shift all

```
<li>
```

inside a

```
<ul>
```

except a particular

```
<li class="active-slide">
```

one position left and right while left button click and right button click.

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="slider_donor">

<li id="slider_1">  
<p class="amount green" id="amount_1">$233,000</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_1">reeeee</h5>
</li>

<li id="slider_2">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_2">$503,000</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_2">monster</h5>
</li>

<li id="slider_3">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_3">$1,003,000</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_3">google</h5>
</li>

<li class="active-slide">
<div class="active-slide-inner">
<h3 id="blackbox">ABC</h3>
<p class="contributed">contributed</p><!-- /.contributed -->
</div><!-- /.active-slide-inner -->
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-dir slider-prev" onclick="prev()">prev</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-dir slider-next" onclick="next()">next</a>

</li>

<li id="slider_4">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_4">yahoo</p>
<h5 id="donor_4">All Donors Supporting</h5>
</li>

<li id="slider_5">                      
    <p class="amount green" id="amount_5">$12</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_5">diff </h5>
</li>

    <li id="slider_6">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_6">$4,003,009</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_6">rediff</h5>
</li>

</ul>
```

i tried this js code :

```
function prev(){
$('#slider_donor > li:first').appendTo('#slider_donor');

}
```

But shift only one way , I cant shift both the ways. And cant stop shifting this particular

```
<li class="active-slide">
```

I want all `<li>` should should shift one place left or right . But this `<li lass="active-slide">` should hold its position , it should be fixed.

So after first left click the order should be like :

```
<ul class="clearfix" id="slider_donor">

<li id="slider_6">  
<p class="amount green" id="amount_6">$233,000</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_6">reeeee</h5>
</li>

<li id="slider_1">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_1">$503,000</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_1">monster</h5>
</li>

<li id="slider_2">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_2">$1,003,000</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_2">google</h5>
</li>

<li class="active-slide">
<div class="active-slide-inner">
<h3 id="blackbox">ABC</h3>
<p class="contributed">contributed</p><!-- /.contributed -->
</div><!-- /.active-slide-inner -->
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-dir slider-prev" onclick="prev()">prev</a>
   <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="slider-dir slider-next" onclick="next()">next</a>

</li>

<li id="slider_3">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_3">yahoo</p>
<h5 id="donor_3">All Donors Supporting</h5>
</li>

<li id="slider_4">                      
    <p class="amount green" id="amount_4">$12</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_4">diff </h5>
</li>

    <li id="slider_5">
<p class="amount green" id="amount_5">$4,003,009</p><!-- /.amount -->
<h5 id="donor_5">rediff</h5>
</li>

</ul>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $('#slider_donor > li:not(.active-slide)') use the not to get the li without the active slide class http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614120/not-class-selector-in-jquery

Comment: It is not working @wilsonrufus , it takes the `<li class="active-slide">` to first position , The structure is like : `<li class="active-slide">
<li id="slider_1">
<li id="slider_2">
<li id="slider_3">
<li id="slider_4">
<li id="slider_5">
<li id="slider_6">`

Comment: i am confused by "one position left and right while left button click and right button click." what do u mean can u please ellaborate

Comment: Basically . if i click left button all the `<li>` will shift one position `right` except the one `<li class='active-slide'>` . This partcular `<li>` will hold its position. If i click left again all `<li>` shift one position `right` again and still this `<li class='active-slide'>` will hold its original position. It will never change. Vice versa while clicking the `right button`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612955/jquery-how-to-move-a-li-to-another-position-in-the-ul-exchange-2-lis try this if its helpful

Answer (score 0):

if i understand good,Try this :

```
$('#slider_donor li').each(function(index, element) {
    var $li=$(element);
    if(! $li.hasClass('active-slide'))
       $li.appendTo('#slider_donor');
});
```

Comment: No this will not work actually . This is similar like `$('#slider_donor > li:not(.active-slide)') `. What it is doing , it takes the `<li class="active-slide"> to first position , The structure is like : <li class="active-slide"> <li id="slider_1"> <li id="slider_2"> <li id="slider_3"> <li id="slider_4"> <li id="slider_5"> <li id="slider_6">`

Comment: I'm little confused.
You want some think like that?

 `var $new_ul=$('<ul></ul>');
 $new_ul.html($('#slider_donor').html());
 $('#slider_donor').remove('li:not(.active-slide)');
 $new_ul.remove('li:has(.active-slide)');
 $new_ul.appendTo('#slider_donor');`

Comment: This code does add a exact new `<ul>` clone of the existing one. It does not modify or shift the `<li>s`.                         Basically i want if i click left button all the `<li>` will shift one position right except the one `<li class='active-slide'>` . This partcular `<li>` will hold its position. If i click left again all `<li>` shift one position right again and still this `<li class='active-slide'>` will hold its original position. It will never change. Vice versa while clicking the right button

Comment: I think I can do anything for you.
Sorry :(

Comment: yeh sure let me know how :)

Comment: No issue @The Fire TITAN , i have finally fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set **class='inactive-slide'** all li except of which has **class='active-slide'**.
And function like below:

```
function prev(){
$('.inactive-slide').appendTo('#slider_donor');

}
```

Comment: It will not help changing class of all other `<li>`. I need to shift other `<li>` also except the `class='active-slide'`

Comment: In this situation editing classes may easier solution.