# How to auto change position of <li> in Jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have an item list in html.

```
<ul>
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
<li id="3">3</li>
<li id="4">4</li>

</ul>
```

I want a jquery to to auto move `<li>` positon like that

```
<ul>
<li id="2">2</li>
<li id="3">3</li>
<li id="4">4</li>
<li id="1">1</li>
</ul>
```

--->

```
<ul>
<li id="3">3</li>
<li id="4">4</li>
<li id="1">1</li>
<li id="2">2</li>
</ul>
```

It will auto change first `<li>` to the last `<li>`

I tried, but it is not worked :(

```
var first = $("ul li:first");
var last = $("ul li:last");
```

Tks for help

Comment: When you want to change the position? After some time interval or anything else?

Comment: try [jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/).

Comment: what do you mean by auto move? is this on event then move that particular element, or just programmatically move it on load?

Comment: I think "auto" means not having to know the id of the element to be moved.

Comment: pos dup of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612955/jquery-how-to-move-a-li-to-another-position-in-the-ul-exchange-2-lis

Comment: @Awlad No, this is about moving to the end, not moving to specific index.

Comment: "auto" means..it dont need click event. Example: per 3 second it will change <li> position

Comment: Oh. Then setInterval.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you need to use `appendTo('ul')`

**[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/tuuVe/9/)**

Answer (score 5):

The appendTo() method inserts HTML elements at the end of the selected elements.

so you must use this

```
$('li:first').appendTo('ul');
```

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MRzu3/)

```
var cont = document.getElementById('container');
cont.appendChild(cont.firstChild);
```

The beauty of [vanilla js](http://vanilla-js.com).

Answer (score 2):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EB2X8/)

```
ul {
    position: relative;
}
ul li {
    position: absolute;
}
ul li:nth-child(1) {
    top: 0;
    -webkit-animation: cycle 4s steps(4, end) infinite;
}
ul li:nth-child(2) {
    top: 18px;
    -webkit-animation: cycle 4s 1s steps(4, end) infinite;
}
ul li:nth-child(3) {
    top: 36px;
    -webkit-animation: cycle 4s 2s steps(4, end) infinite;
}
ul li:nth-child(4) {
    top: 54px;
    -webkit-animation: cycle 4s 3s steps(4, end) infinite;
}
@-webkit-keyframes cycle {
    from { top: 0 }
    to { top: 72px }
}
```

The beauty of [CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation).

Answer (score 1):

Totally agree with answer of `Feroz Akbar`.

You can also do another way also like

```
window.setInterval(function(){
   $('#MainUl > li:last').after($('#MainUl > li:first'));
}, 1000);
```

Here is [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LJQFe/2/) for the same.